# define authentication-failure-url to be `{currentpage}?login_error=1`?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring MVC, Spring security and Apache tiles.
I have login div that appears in every page (in case the user is not authenticated yet).
This is the configuration:

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/registration.html" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/about.html" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/search.html" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login.html" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/logout.html" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/post.html" access="hasAnyRole('USER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />
    <form-login default-target-url='/search.html'
                authentication-failure-url="/login.html?login_error=1" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/logout.html" />
</http>
```

The problem is:
Assume the user enters to search.html and enters invalid login details. But then the user redirect to `/login.html?login_error=1` instead of redirecting to `search.html?login_error=1`. How can I define authentication-failure-url to be `{currentpage}?login_error=1` ?

Answer (score 9):

You need to customize the `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler` a bit, for example by an new `RedirectStrategy`.

Before starting: you should have a look at the source of this classes to understand what they do:

- `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` and its super class `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` -- That is the filter that triggers the authentication
- `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler` -- this is responsible to do something if an authentication is required (it is invoked by `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler).
- `DefaultRedirectStrategy` -- used by `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler` to do the redirct.
- `FormLoginBeanDefinitionParser` -- parses the XML `security:form-login` element -- You should read it to understand what how the beans are created and referenced!!

You should write your own `RedirectStrategy`, lets call it `MyAppendParameterRedirectStrategy` (may have first a look at `DefaultRedirectStrategy`). It needs only one method: `void sendRedirect(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String url)`. At least you should do the same like `DefaultRedirectStrategy` but instead of returning the (login) url in the `calculateRedirectUrl` you should calculate the url like `stripParams(getRequestURL()) + "?login_error=1"`

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.security.web.RedirectStrategy;

public class MyAppendParameterRedirectStrategy implements RedirectStrategy {

    @Override
    public void sendRedirect(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final String url) throws IOException {
        String redirectUrl = calculateRedirectUrl(request.getRequestURL().toString());
        redirectUrl = response.encodeRedirectURL(redirectUrl);
        response.sendRedirect(redirectUrl);
    }

    private String calculateRedirectUrl(final String requestUrl) {
        //Attention this parameter striping is only proof of concept!
        return StringUtils.substringBeforeLast(requestUrl, "?") + "?login_error=1";
    }
}
```

The Second part is that you need to change the spring configuration (therefore you should read the classes I mentioned about)
I think the configuration should be like this (but I do not have tested it):

```
<security:form-login login-processing-url="/login/j_spring_security_check" login-page="/login" authentication-failure-handler-ref="simpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler"/>

<bean id="SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
   <property="defaultFailureUrl" value="NotNullButWeDoNotUseIt" />
   <property="redirectStrategy">
      <bean class="MyAppendParameterRedirectStrategy"/>
   </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks for the direction, but request.getRequestURL() gives me 'http://localhost:8080/j_spring_security_check' and not the current page.

Comment: @Naor You can get actual by invoking request.getHeader("referer");